# How to edit the content of renderings defined on Partial Designs with the Experience Editor on page level?

Tags: sxa

I created a partial design called *Footer*, and added a *Link List* rendering to this Footer by using the presentation details.

I assigned this partial design to the page design *Default* and assigned this page design to the homepage.

In this situation the only way to change the content of the *Link List* rendering via the Experience Editor is by opening the partial design in the xEditor. So when I open the Experience Editor for the homepage I'm not able to change the links in the *Link List* rendering.

I don't know whether this is by design or maybe there is a setting which can change this this behaviour?

I would like all renderings to be editable on page level even when they are defined on partial designs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Editing partial designs can only be done on the partial design itself - that is by design. There is no setting to change that. https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_accelerator/designing/page_design/create_and_change_a_partial_design

A partial design is an item on itself. So you need to get to that 'item' in the experience editor to change it:

1. On the ribbon, on the Experience Accelerator tab, click Partial
   Design.
2. Select the partial design that you want to change.

As a change to a partial designs can have consequences on lots of pages, there is some logic in the design choice to edit them separately. Otherwise editors might make changes without knowing the results.

I understand your question and feeling to edit everything on the page itself, but I'm afraid that is not the way it works.

Comment: This is only partially true.
Data sources for renderings within Partial Designs can be set to use the "page:" prefix, which will cause the page instance to read a data item from the page data folder.
A user with admin access can in fact edit the fields in these renderings from a page in EE.
I'm trying to figure out how to set permissions so a user in a Role can edit these fields as well.

Comment: Just need Write access to the page data folder, that allows a non-admin role to edit field values of renderings that come from a partial design and use data sources that are in the page data folder.

Answer (score 0):

You can access these in the Content Editor under the Data directory.
[image: SxA Data Directory]