# Creating footer and header components in SXA using Page and Partial Designs from Shared site

Tags: sxa, experience-editor

I am trying to create a footer component in SXA 1.8, Sitecore 9.0.2.

The current solution setup consists of one tenant, one shared site ('Site A') and multiple regular (not shared) sites (let's call one of them 'Site B'). Site A is going to be supplied as a base for all the sites of Site B type. All the other sites should be created using page designs created in Site A, but nobody from authors or designers of Site B will not be able to edit anything in Site A.

It does not seem to be possible to create the partial design for header/footer in Site A and then to share it from there to be able to edit it inside Site B. How this can be achieved?

The approach I tried:

- All page designs are stored under Site A and are shared across all the sites.
- There are two partial designs created for header and footer under Site A, which are used on each of the page designs.
- I created a footer item in settings (/Settings/Footer), and I added a branch so it will be created automatically in this location for any new site while the navigation module will be added.
- On the footer partial design in Site A, I wanted to add a datasource as /Settings/Footer item with SXA $site token: query:$site/Settings/Footer. It throws an error but the concept works - when I open a page from Site B in Experience Editor I can see that my view is appearing but I am not able to edit the item content in EE. This is where this concept fails.

Is there an easy way to be able to edit the component content on Site B while the Partial and Page designs are stored under shared site A?

Comment: In general, it is impossible to edit content from partial while being on other items.
https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/a/6755/16
With the concept of page relative data sources, you might be able to expose fields but I have to ask you for more information. What exactly would you like to edit on SiteB from partial in SiteA (fields content, presentation structure)?

Comment: I know it is not possible to make it work like this, I just can't find an easy solution to do it differently without moving all the partial and page designs from Site A to Site B and have different ones for each of the sites. On the footer I would like to edit content - some text fields and a few multilists with links.

Comment: I am afraid that this will not meet all your requirements but, you could try with `local` keyword for data sources
https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/a/2474/16
I never used it with shared sites but I think it could be possible. Try to create partials and use the one from SiteA as a BasePartial. This way you should be able to keep a presentation on SiteA but data sources under SiteB. The disadvantage is you will need separate datasources for each site.